# How we can control function from other page in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I make small app this app have two pages. First page main page then second page. now in each pages I add function  this function to can add new data in MySQL database. Now my problem the user is work in main page and when click button add in main page I need to make the method on the other page work as well in same time.

So how we can control function from other page? How I can call AddNewColor() in MainPage in button (add new data).

Note: This is just an example of what I am trying to do also to understand the idea and the problem. In my full application, I display the second page on the first page to display a set of images.

Main page code:

```
void main() {
  runApp(MainPage());
}
class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MainPage> {
  TextEditingController NameController = TextEditingController();
  Future AddNewData() async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("**********", ),
        body: {
          "Name": NameController.text,
        }
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    } else {
      throw Exception('Send Failed');
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
          body: Column(children: [
            TextFormField(
              controller: NameController,
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
        
                 ),

            ),

            ElevatedButton(
              child: Text('add new data'),
              onPressed: () {
                AddNewData();
              },
            ),
          ],)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second Page code:

```
class secondpage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<secondpage> {

  TextEditingController ColorController = TextEditingController();
  Future AddNewColor() async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("**********", ),
        body: {
          "Color": ColorController.text,
        }
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    } else {
      throw Exception('Send Failed');
    }
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Column(children: [
          TextFormField(
            controller: ColorController,
            decoration: InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
             ),

          ),

          ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('add new color'),
            onPressed: () {
              AddNewColor();
            },
          ),
        ],)
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how these two page related to each other?

Comment: you want to call AddNewData() in both page?

Comment: @eamirho3ein Note: This is just an example of what I am trying to do also to understand the idea and the problem. In my full application, I display the second page on the first page to display a set of images. I updated the question

Comment: @eamirho3ein I want   call AddNewColor() in MainPage in button (add new data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `AddNewColor()` out of `secondpage` class:

```
Future AddNewColor(TextEditingController colorController) async {
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse("**********", ),
        body: {
          "Color": ColorController.text,
        }
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    } else {
      throw Exception('Send Failed');
    }
  }

class secondpage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<secondpage> {
  ...
}
```

now you can call it every where you want. Note that use return way to pass the result data.

update:
try define `ColorController` here:

```
class _MyAppState extends State<MainPage> {
  TextEditingController NameController = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController ColorController = TextEditingController();
  Future AddNewData() async {
  ...
  }
...
}
```

then change your second page to receive it like this:

```
class secondpage extends StatefulWidget {
  final TextEditingController ColorController;
  secondpage(this.ColorController);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
```

now you can use `ColorController` in both pages with `AddNewColor`.

Comment: I can't do that. If I do that I can't use variable as example TextEditingController in function

Comment: Undefined name 'ColorController'. I will get as this message Undefined name 'ColorController'.

Comment: you can pass it to function like this: AddNewColor(TextEditingController)

Comment: where I have to call AddNewColor() then in secondpage ? to pass variable  to it? or not need that?

Comment: you should define this ColorController in first page and pass it to second page, in this way you can use it in both pages.

Comment: Doesn't this helpful for you? @MAl

Comment: still no I still try and also waiting for other suggestions

Comment: this does not work or you are not understand it?

Comment: I try it to make it work but I have many error (not understand it)